# Combining 3 wall switches, which are currently in the same box

Tags: electrical, switch

These 3 switches are sharing the same hot wire in the same box. I want to combine them into 1 switch that will control all 3 lights. The lights are basic outdoor porch lights and are each on separate basic standard house switches. I want to eliminate 2 of the switches so all 3 can be activated by a single switch. I bought a more heavy duty switch to use even though I don't think I need it. 
My plan is to use the hot wire that is there and pigtail the other 3 wires that control the lights.

Can you tell me if I'm heading in the right direction and if not, what Should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only question is what is the load? The wires are they 12 or 14 gauge the reason I ask if this is a 20 amp circuit powering 3 circuits of lighting you may need the heavy duty switch. If it is 14 gauge on a 15 amp circuit a standard switch will be fine and your plan is code compliant.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like what I would do.  Whenever rewiring like that, I like to clean the copper either by scraping it off with the wire stripper, cutting it shorter and re-stripping it, or light sanding.  I've also heard about dipping the copper in vinegar gets it brite and shiny again.

What are you going to do with the 2 empty slots?